# Google Analytics how to get metric for 'number of active users on website at any one time'

Tags: google-analytics

In Google analytics how can i get a metric to put "number of active users on website at any one time". I want to put it against past date periods.

I.E I was scrolling through the metrics, trying to add a widget to my dashboard but, I can't find this metric!

It looks like it's possible because google analytics uses it on their standard report, real-time, "current active visitors on website"

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply, you can't out of the box. There are some limitations in real-time reports and the ways GA counts unique visitors.

However, if you do not need a detailed analysis, this [custom report](https://www.google.com/analytics/web/template?uid=ziIDyGhfR9SGwc8yDuMdSQ) might do the work (just import it for your Analytics Profile/View and click *Customization* tab). It basically shows the generic numbers (you can change them to fit your needs) according to hour of a day.

Add any secondary metrics to find out how numbers change in days/weekends etc. Or you can slice the data with segments and see if some traffic is more active in the morning etc.

[image]

Hope hits helps.

PS: Beware of data sampling...